# WebClient.UploadString appears to be passing a GET when I'm explicitly doing a POST

Tags: c#, system.net

This is a weird one can I'm not sure what is happening.  I have a testing project that calls my api.  Recently, it appears that when I'm calling a none https website (ie http), it's changing my verb from a "POST" to a "GET".  My code is

```
response = client.UploadString(URL, "POST", myItemsObject);
```

On my API, the first thing I do is log the request, including the verb.

Comment: `However, when the URL is a http://, then verb is "GET".` What happens if you try to do the exact same thing in Postman? My _guess_ is that the endpoint you are posting to is redirecting to https (and switching to GET in the process).

Comment: It works fine with Postman for my http:// call.  I did a wireshark trace, and the verb that it was passing a "GET".  It looks like the verb is being changed

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Why is this an issue? If https works - why not just always use https?

Comment: `I did a wireshark trace, and the verb that it was passing a "GET"` How did the wireshark for Postman differ from your WebClient.UploadString?

Answer (score 0):

Doh!  I figured it out... On my web servers in the web.config I had

```
<sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" mode="InProc" />
```

This was causing AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 to be passed in the URL as part of the query string.  So it was hitting the web server as GET instead of a PUT.  I changed cookieless="false" and it works.